# What does it mean for RFC 3339 to be "a profile of" ISO 8601?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, terminology

[RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339) says:

> This document defines a date and time format for use in Internet protocols that is a profile of the ISO 8601 standard for representation of dates and times using the Gregorian calendar.

The same terminology is used in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/522281) comparing the two standards.

What does it mean for a document / standard to be "a profile of" another?

Comment: You need to read ISO 8601, in particular ISO/WD 8601-2 Annex B, where the term "profile" is defined. It's not a regular English meeting; rather it's tech standards jargon.

Comment: As Mark says, it's not a regular English meeting; rather it's tech standards jargon.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, Mark Beadles sagely wrote:

> You need to read ISO 8601, in particular [ISO/WD 8601-2 Annex B](https://www.loc.gov/standards/datetime/iso-tc154-wg5_n0039_iso_wd_8601-2_2016-02-16.pdf#page=25), where the term "profile" is defined. It's not a regular English [meaning]; rather it's tech standards jargon.

Comment: Would that be meaning, not meeting?

Comment: @Xanne Good catch!

Answer (score 1):

The standard ISO 8601 is not publicly accessible but there is a preview of its part including *Terms and definitions*:

https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso:8601:-2:ed-1:v1:en:term:3.1.2.1

There we can discover the meaning of these terms in the context of ISO 8601:

- **feature** - single function or group of functions
- **profile** - subset of features described in a standard or a set of standards

So a profile of the ISO 8601 standard defines a subset of the standard.